# How to check if object fields are empty before inserting into mongooseDB from CSV file - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, csv, parsing, mongoose

My code is working correctly, I wanted to add some error checking to make sure no object with empty fields could be inserted into the DB. I am having some trouble getting that part working right. The data is coming from a local csv file like so:

**TempCSV.csv**

```
name, address, ID, contactInfo
bob, 214 elm, 123, email
joe, 817 beach, 321, email
,45 hollywood,456,
```

The first two lines should be inserted but not the last one because it is missing *name*, which is a required field. So basically each field needs to be checked while it is parsed to see if it is empty or not.

Here is my code
**dbparser.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const csvtojson = require("csvtojson");
const router = require("express").Router();

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    ID: String,
    contactInfo: String
});

const userModel= mongoose.model("User");
const async = require('async');

csvtojson()
        .fromFile("TempCSV.csv")
        .then(csvData => {
            async.eachSeries(csvData,(data,callback) => {
                  let entity = {
                    name: data.name,
                    address: data.owner,
                    ID: data.ownerID,
                    };

                    userModel.create(entity, function(err)
                    {
                        if(err) return callback(err);
                        return callback(null);    
                    })
               },
                (err) => {
                     if(err) console.log(err); 
                     console.log("users are successfully imported!!!");
                });            
});
```

I thought adding the const userSchema would prevent it from adding empty fields but it did not.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can another function which checks the emptiness of the object passed. It will return `true` if `obj` has all `keys` have a truthy value, returns `false` otherwise.

```js
function hasKeys(obj, keys) {
  return keys.every(key => !!obj[key])
}
```

And then check the object before inserting into the database.

Comment: I get an error: Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: keys is not defined, when I try this method

Comment: `keys` will be an array of required keys. Call function like this- `hasKeys(data, ['name', 'address'])`. Add other keys that you want to check